# How to render a message when service is down using ASP.NET 4.7.2 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
private string Search(string ids, string qryStr)
{
    var ws = new searchws.AppSearchSoapClient("AppSearchSoapClient", ConfigHelper.search_Url);
    // rest of the logic here   
}
```

This is the code snippet where we are binding service. If the service is down, how can we render a message saying "Service is down, kindly try again later"?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what actually happens in your code when the service you are trying to use "does not do what you expect it to do", it will probably throw an error in your code. Try using a `try_catch` block?

```
  private string Search(string ids, string qryStr)
    {
      Try {
        var ws = new searchws.AppSearchSoapClient("AppSearchSoapClient", ConfigHelper.search_Url);
        // rest of the logic here   
          }
      Catch {
        //issue with connecting to service.
        //do something here
          }
    }
```

Comment: catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        if(((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)((System.Net.WebException)ex.InnerException).Response).StatusDescription == "Not Found")
                        {

                            Response.Write("<script>alert(' Service is down...Please try after sometimes');</script>");
                            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Record Inserted Successfully')", true);
                        }

Comment: In catch blok I wrote like this ...but the messagebox is not showing in UI level....I need to show the error message in UI when service is down

Comment: You'll have to debug...

Why not make it easier to start with? Don't catch a "specific error", and just update a label on the front end?

Catch {
lblerror.visible = true;
lblerror.text = "Some error message";
}